# why am i getting segmentation error on hackerearth for a sorting question

Tags: c

i was getting segmentation error on hacker earth with this code.

I know its a invalid memory reference error, but I can't seem to find the cause of the error in my code.

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int* awseomeSort (int N, int* arr) {
   // Write down your code
   int awesome_sort[N];
   int odd_arr[N],even_arr[N],o=0,e=0;
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(arr[i]%2==0){
           even_arr[e]=arr[i];
           e++;
       }
       else {odd_arr[o]=arr[i];
       o++;}
    }
   int sorted_even[e];
int k=0;
   for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<e;j++){
            if(even_arr[j]%5==0){
                if(even_arr[j]>even_arr[i]){
                        sorted_even[k]=even_arr[j];
                        k++;
                }
                else if(even_arr[i]%5==0){
                    sorted_even[k]=even_arr[i];
                    k++;}
                }
                else {if(even_arr[i]%5==0){
                    sorted_even[k]=even_arr[i];
                    k++;
                } else if(j>i){
                 sorted_even[k]=even_arr[j];
                 k++;
                } else {
                    sorted_even[k]=even_arr[i];
                 k++;
                }
                }
        }
}
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    if(i<k){
    awesome_sort[i]=sorted_even[i];
}
else {int m=0;
    awesome_sort[i]=odd_arr[m];
    m++;
}}
return awesome_sort;
   
}


int main() {
    int out_n;
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(int t_i = 0; t_i < T; t_i++)
    {
        int N;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int i_arr;
        int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(N));
        for(i_arr = 0; i_arr < N; i_arr++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i_arr]);

        int* out_ = awseomeSort(N, arr);
        printf("%d", out_[0]);
        for(int i_out_ = 1; i_out_ <  N; i_out_++)
            printf(" %d", out_[i_out_]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

please help me with the wrongs or mistakes i'm making here

ignore below:
Maybe you're right, I changed all the array sizes to '100000', but now I'm getting time limit exceeded.But I have two questions: 1. Why do you specifically state the value upto '100000' ? Shouldn't it be like '32767' ? 2. Is there something else I could do to get around this problem ? Because my code looks too simplistic when I compared it to other submissions which had used a lot of complicated functions and methods which I am unaware of as of now. Mine works totally fine and gives the right output.

Comment: `int awesome_sort[N];`, `int sorted_even[e];` these are [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) on stack, so obviously it fails when the size becomes too large. You must allocate memory on heap yourself

Comment: Additionally, the function awseomeSort returns awesome_sort, which is an array allocated on the stack, which goes out of scope upon return... which is another reason to do what @phuclv suggested (as if you needed another reason).

Comment: OT:  when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The most critical problem is: untitled2.c:51:8: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]"